Weird behaviour using simple variables and functions
I do not understand why and how result of the below code is obtained. Please explain every step of the process.
You can experiment more by passing b as a parameter to myFunc, but still the output is same.
let a = myFunc()
var b = 19

func myFunc() -> Int {
    b
}

func changeBAndGetA() -> Int  {
    b = 16
    return a
}

print(changeBAndGetA(), a, b)
// outputs 0 0 16

I expected it to be 16 16 16. because I read the global variables are lazily evaluated

I expected it to be 16 16 16. because I read the global variables are lazily evaluated

I ran it on storyboard. I do not know how to run the same code (global scope) in an xcode project. Please guide me. Thank you for taking your time to look into this.

You can't run code "on storyboard". Did you mean "playground"?

yes :) sorry about that

It seems like you are running this in a playground/as a swift script, where statements are allowed at the top level. In such an environment, the variables you declare at top level "look like" global variables, but aren't actually lazily initialised. Your code is simply run from top to bottom.
let a = myFunc() is the first line that is run, but b is not initialised yet. Looking at the assembly output, b at this point would be all 0 bits. While for Int this is a value that makes sense (the integer 0), the program would crash if b is String or Array. So a is initialised to 0. Then var b = 19 is run, and finally the print call.
Similar behaviours have been discussed numerous times on Swift Forums (1, 2), and multiple issues are submitted to the apple/swift repo (1, 2, 3) that are still open. For now, you just have to accept that variables in top level code are just kind of "broken". Something as simple as
print(x)
var x = [1]

crashes (segfaults), because "all zeroes" doesn't make sense as an Array.
Here is a quote from one of the GitHub issues:

Right, unfortunately there's a difference between "top-level globals", which are globals defined at the top-level where you can also evaluate expressions, and globals in regular contexts, that is, not main.swift. The difference can also be seen if you take your single swift file, create a @main entry-point, and compile with -parse-as-library. That will treat the declarations at the top-level like the "regular" contexts.

So if you compile:
var a = myFunc()
var b = 19

func myFunc() -> Int {
    b
}

func changeBAndGetA() -> Int  {
    b = 16
    return a
}

@main
struct Foo {
    static func main() {
        print(changeBAndGetA(), a, b)
    }
}

with swiftc -parse-as-libary yourFile.swift, then run the executable, you will see the expected result of 16 16 16.

Thank you for the references added in the answer

When the swift code executes, both a and b are initially treated as if they hold the default integer value of 0. This behavior occurs because the variables are declared within the scope but have not yet been explicitly assigned a value at the time they are first accessed.
The behavior you're seeing is analogous to the following scenario:
print(c)  //prints 0
var c = 5

In this example, even though 'c' is printed before it's explicitly set to 5, the compiler treats it as initialized to 0 at the point of use. This doesn't cause an error because 'c' is defined in the file.
when line one runs, it sets 'a' to 'b' which is 0. when the print statement runs it calls changeBAndGetA() which changes 'b' to 16, returns 'a' which is 0. then it prints 'a' which is 0 then 'b' which is 0.

Thank you for the answer. But I read global variables are lazily evaluated. Meaning myFunc should not be evaluated until a is accessed

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
