Why does Swift allow variable usage before declaration at the global scope but not within functions?
I'm encountering a strange behavior in Swift regarding the order of variable declarations. At the global scope, Swift seems to allow the use of a variable before its declaration, but within a function, it enforces stricter rules.
let a = b + 4
let b = 5

// prints 4
print(a)

In the global scope, a is initialized with b + 4 before b is declared, yet it prints 4. I expected it to either throw an error or return 9 after both variables are initialized.
Inside a function, Swift correctly enforces the order of variable declarations, resulting in an error: "Use of local variable 'y' before its declaration."
// error: Use of local variable 'y' before its declaration
func foo() -> Int {
    let x = y + 4
    let y = 5
    
    return x
}


Why does Swift allow this seemingly inconsistent behavior at the global scope, where it uses the variable before its declaration, instead of either throwing an error or correctly computing the value?
Any explanation into this would be appreciated!

From what I understand from the bug reports, they didn't deliberately allow this to happen. It's a (bad) side effect of allowing statements at the top level. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78396929/5133585.

Variables declared at the top level are global variables, so they can accessed from everywhere, including before they are declared textually.
This logic is fine for proper Swift/Xcode projects, but it falls apart when you can also write statements at the top level, like in a Swift script/Swift playground. This allows you to do nonsensical things like:
print(x) // prints 0
let x = 10

There has been many issues on the Swift Github repo to change global variables in a context that allows top level statements as if they are local variables declared in a function.
Now to answer the question of "why", in #73300, it is said that this behaviour is a "historical accident".

In top-level code, Swift behaves differently, defies common user expectations, perform badly, and crashes in inscrutable ways. This leads to confusion and misunderstanding among Swift developers and bad publicity among potential Swift adopters. The differences in Swift top-level code are subtle but important. As new language and performance features are added, the differences increase and become more problematic.
This all comes down to the historical "accident" of pretending that top-level variables are globals, and initializing them in a way that can never be sound.


Yes, I think this behavior is the same even you try it in an app or playground. Inside a ContentView might be different.

Now I'm studying C and would be nice to have operators like * and & that are used in conjunction with pointers (maybe that would fix somehow this issue, idk)

The Swift Programming Language: Properties: Global and Local Variables tells us:

Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike lazy stored properties, global constants and variables don’t need to be marked with the lazy modifier.
Local constants and variables are never computed lazily.

So, the order in which globals are declared does not matter. They are evaluated lazily, i.e., as you reference them. You just need to avoid circular references (but the compiler will catch this).
But, local variables are not computed lazily, but rather evaluated sequentially. Therefore, the order matters. You cannot reference a local variable before it has been declared.

So lazy is some sort of thunk?

“Lazy” just means that its initial value isn’t calculated until the first time it’s used. Globals are initialized in the order that they’re referenced during execution, not the order that they appear with the source file(s).

@Adrian – Personally, I might hesitate to use the term “thunk”, as (a) that is not the terminology that Apple uses (if anything, they talk about dispatch_once pattern) and (b) it might suggest a particular implementation detail that might not apply. But it might be an apt analogy, at the very least.
